# Is there any way to refresh div when clicked on bootstrap tab in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problem as below:

```
    <div class="btn-choice">
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn active" id="btn-a">A</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">B</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">C</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-a">D</button>
    </div>


$("#active-all").click(function(){
    $('.btn').toggleClass('active');
});
```

I have added `active` class to button whenever I click active-all button. I found this `active` class still exist to every tab that I have those HTML button. So that I want refresh that `div` every time I clicked tab.

I try with jQuery `load()` and `reload()` but this seems not solving my problem.

**UDATE**
I have added `active` class to button when I clicked active-all button. I found this `active` class still exist even I go forward or backward to another page. So that I want to find a way refresh that div every time I go forward or backward to another page.

Comment: If you are fetching data from database or some file. you need to add event `onclick` and call ajax based to fetch data from database or file.

Comment: your description is unclear. can you please elaborate a bit more on the issue?

Comment: `id="btn-a"` `id="btn-a"` `id="btn-a"` ... ID should be unique.

Comment: Hi, where exactly you need to add active class?

Comment: Please read my update. I'm trying to explain my problem. But I may be not clear. It's seems hard for me to tell my what exactly my problem is.

Comment: it could be possibly a browser-specific issue. I recently faced a similar issue on firefox where elements were cached. Can you please try some different browsers to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Need something like this?

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){    
    if (this.id === 'active-all') {      
      $(".btn", $(this).parent()).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="firstTab">
  <div class="btn-choice">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-a">D</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="secondTab">
  <div class="btn-choice">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="active-all">All</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn-a">C</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-a">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```